# How to deal with code that change its address among different execution

Tags: ida, windows, packers

I think that this is a basic need of every reverser so this question may have been asked in other places but really, I'm unable to find an answer. Maybe I'm asking the wrong question.

So, supposing I have a DLL that change base VA among different execution because of ASLR, in windows I can set DLLCharacteristic to make sure is loaded every time at the same address (losing eventually the signature). But what for generic code?

Suppose that a program allocate a buffer, copy some data, decrypt it then run it. In IDA, of course I can take a snapshot of memory, analyze it, put label and so on, but if I run the program the second time chances are the address are changed, so I can't benefit of my previous analysis.

Is there a way map an arbiratry address with a previous analyzed section in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To map your section to another address use **Edit -> Segments** and than **Move current segment** in IDA, you can even rebase the whole program in this menu.

I hope I have understood your question. Sorry if not :)

Comment: It works like a charm. Sorry for the dumb question. I've always tried the opposite from the "program segmentation" view and it never worked. Thanks, this semplify a lot my work!!